# How to change cakephp3 default pagination limit 20 to 100

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

How to change cakephp3 default pagination limit 20 to 100

Am new to cakephp anyone please guide me, how to set default limit now is 20, but i want 100

Comment: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/pagination.html#limit-the-maximum-number-of-rows-per-page

Comment: Its better to define in config and then get that value for all pages.

Answer (score 0):

**xxxxxcontroller.php**

add code below to your controller

```
 public $helpers = [
           'Paginator' => ['templates' => 'paginator-templates']
       ];
       public $paginate = [
        'limit' =>100
    ];
    public function index() 
    {       
            $users = $this->Users->find('all');     
            $users=  $this->set('users', $this->paginate());
     }
```

You can adjust the value of limit to any number you want. Like for the one you wanted change the value of limit to 100

**index.ctp**

```
<?= $this->Paginator->first("First");   ?>
  <?= $this->Paginator->prev('< ' . __('Previous')) ?> 
  <?= $this->Paginator->numbers();  ?>   

           <?= $this->Paginator->next(__('Next') . ' >') ?> 
           <?= $this->Paginator->last("Last"); ?>
        </ul>
 <p>Showing <?= $this->Paginator->counter() ?></p>
```